# How could Bean not know this in Shadow Puppets

Tags: enders-game, clones, genetic-engineering

From Shadow Puppets:

> "Yes, yes," said Anton, "so I gleaned from Sister Carlotta, God rest her soul. But why did you, and you alone, sneak out of your bed and go into the bathroom and hide in such a dangerous and difficult place? Scarcely a year old, too. So precocious. So desperate to survive. Yet genetically identical to **all your brothers**, da?"
>
> "Cloned," said Bean, "so ... yes.

However, Bean was only genetically identical to five of his brothers (including Nikolai). The other six were from a separate clone. So how could Bean not know that? He lived with his parents for a year at that point already.

Comment: I don't see the quote as saying "genetically identical to every infant in the room".

Comment: @DVK How does **all your brothers** not imply that he was genetically identical to all  the males?

Comment: because it doesn't imply that **everyone** in the room was his brother.

Comment: @DVK I don't see where you're going with this. They were all his brothers based on other parts in the series. Do you want quotes for that from Ender's Shadow?

Comment: the point is, this is a discrepancy in English language, not in the plot. All != "everyone in the room".

Comment: @DVK There are two facts that appear inconsistent. 1. Bean is genetically identical to **all his brothers** 2. Bean had 6 brother **not** genetically identical to him. How are you addressing that?

Comment: I'm just reading it as imprecise English. Either by accident, or by design (Anton isn't a native speaker). Could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Though Bean was originally genetically identical to Nicoli as a fertilized embryo, Bean's DNA was altered to activate the "hyper-intelligence" gene-cluster. The point being: Though genetically similar, their DNA was not identical; which is no small difference considering the resulting dimorphism both intellectually and physiologically. Consider peafowl: the genetic difference between a peacock and a peahen comes down to a few "lines of gattaca", however the physiological dimorphism is extremely apparent considering the ornamentation, coloring, and size differences. With genes, being 99.999% identical can lead to extreme differences.

It is possible that when Bean answered that he was "genetically identical" he was referring to the gene's that mattered the most: those being the activated "super-intelligence" genes.

Comment: Bean was only 50% identical to the other six boys. They were from a separate egg. There's a difference between that and the 99.999% that he and Nicoli shared. And the quote from Bean: "Cloned," said Bean, "so ... yes." shows that he meant that they were perfect clones of him genetically. Sharing 50% like any two brothers doesn't mean genetically identical.